# Jquery + Toggle with double callback

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying to use a toggle() with a callback for on/off:

```
instantMsgTabOptions.click(function() {
instantMsgOptions.toggle(function() {
        $('table.instantMsgTabs td.instantMsgTabOptions').css('color','#849C00').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    },function() {
        $('table.instantMsgTabs td.instantMsgTabOptions').css('color','#000').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    });
});
```

this doesn't work - any advice on what needs to be changed?

thx

Comment: can you add your some portion of html code?

Comment: just a button that either shows or hides a DIV.

Comment: `instantMsgTabOptions` are you getting this values from `$('buton')`
or try binding in function itself in `$('button id/class').click(function() { });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create css rule with:

```
.myclass {
  color: #849C00;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And use `toggleClass` like this:

```
instantMsgTabOptions.click(function() {
   $('table.instantMsgTabs td.instantMsgTabOptions').toggleClass('myclass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is already an event listener for click, thus use

```
instantMsgOptions.toggle(function() {
        $('table.instantMsgTabs td.instantMsgTabOptions').css('color','#849C00').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
},function() {
        $('table.instantMsgTabs td.instantMsgTabOptions').css('color','#000').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

Comment: You provided a link to the docs; however, nowhere in the docs is that method used the way you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
   instantMsgTabOptions.toggle(function() {
    $('table.instantMsgTabs td.instantMsgTabOptions').css('color','#849C00').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
},function() {
    $('table.instantMsgTabs td.instantMsgTabOptions').css('color','#000').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```